# IronPython Spotfire: Creating Hierarchy Column and moving associated Filter to TableGroup.Subgroup

Tags: filter, ironpython, hierarchy, spotfire

I am working on an IronPython script for TIBCO Spotfire to create a new hierarchy column and then move the filter associated with the hierarchy to a TableGroup.Subgroup.

In my script I am doing the following:
1. Retrieving the table group "Result Table Group"
2. Retrieving the data table "Result Table"
3. creating a new subgroup "Result hierarchy subgroup"
4. Looping through all filters in the table group and
- hiding the filter
- creating a hierarchy column for the filter-associated column
- try to move the filter to the subgroup

Here is the relevant part from the code:

```
filterPanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel

# get the correct tableGroup
for tableGroup in filterPanel.TableGroups:
    if tableGroup.Name == "Result Table Group":
        resultTableGroup = tableGroup

# get the correct dataTable
for table in Document.Data.Tables:
    if table.Name == "Result Table":
        resultDataTable = table

# create new subgroup
hierarchyfilterGroup = resultTableGroup.AddNewSubGroup("Result hierarchy subgroup")

filterPanel.InteractiveSearchPattern = ""
for filterHandle in filterPanel.FiltersMatchingSearchPattern:
    tableGroupFilterHandle = resultTableGroup.GetFilter(filterHandle.FilterReference.Name)

    if tableGroupFilterHandle != None:
       tableGroupFilterHandle.Visible = False # hide filter in table group

       # create a new hiearchy column
       hierarchyColName = tableGroupFitlerHandle.FilterReference.Name + " - process hierarchy"
       hierarchyExpressions = List[str]()
       hierarchyExpressions.Add("[" + tableGroupFitlerHandle.FilterReference.Name + "]")
       hierarchyExpressions.Add("[Process]")
       hierarchy = HierarchyDefinition(HierarchyNestingMode.Nested, hierarchyExpressions)
       resultDataTable.Columns.AddHierarchyColumn(hierarchyColName, hierarchy)

       # try to get the hierarchy associated filter
       hieararchyFilterHandle = tableGroup.GetFilter(hierarchyColName)
       if hiearchyFilterHandle != None:
           hierarchyfilterGroup.Add(hierarchyFilter.FilterReference)
```

However,  `tableGroup.GetFilter(hierarchyColName)` always returns `None` for the hiearchy columns. As a result of running the script, I get the hierarchy filters correctly and I also see the subgroup correctly, but the hierarchy filters are not sorted into the subgroup.

Here are some other things I have tried:

1. Searching the whole FilterPanel for the hiearachy filter

```
FilterPanel.InteractiveSearchPattern = hierarchyColName
for filterHandle in filterPanel.FiltersMatchingSearchPattern:
    ...
```

--> does not find any MatchingFilters

2. Refreshing the dataTable before trying to find the filter

```
resultDataTable.Refresh()
...
```

​​​​​​​--> has no effect on the result

3. Using a separate second loop after the first loop for moving the filters

Could you please help me moving the hierarchy filter to the newly created subgroup?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out and leaving the answer in case someone else ever gets stuck in the same place.

```
filterPanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel

# get the correct tableGroup
for tableGroup in filterPanel.TableGroups:
    if tableGroup.Name == "Result Table Group":
        resultTableGroup = tableGroup

# get the correct dataTable
for table in Document.Data.Tables:
    if table.Name == "Result Table":
        resultDataTable = table

# create new subgroup
hierarchyfilterGroup = resultTableGroup.AddNewSubGroup("Result hierarchy subgroup")

filterPanel.InteractiveSearchPattern = ""
for filterHandle in filterPanel.FiltersMatchingSearchPattern:
    tableGroupFilterHandle = resultTableGroup.GetFilter(filterHandle.FilterReference.Name)

    if tableGroupFilterHandle != None:
       tableGroupFilterHandle.Visible = False # hide filter in table group

       # create a new hiearchy column
       hierarchyColName = tableGroupFitlerHandle.FilterReference.Name + " - process hierarchy"
       hierarchyExpressions = List[str]()
       hierarchyExpressions.Add("[" + tableGroupFitlerHandle.FilterReference.Name + "]")
       hierarchyExpressions.Add("[Process]")
       hierarchy = HierarchyDefinition(HierarchyNestingMode.Nested, hierarchyExpressions)
       resultDataTable.Columns.AddHierarchyColumn(hierarchyColName, hierarchy)

       colExists, hierarchyCol = resultDataTable.Columns.TryGetValue(hierarchyColName)
       resultTableGroup.FilterCollectionReference.AddNewFilter(hierarchyCol)

       # move the filter to the subgroup
       hierarchyFilterHandle = resultTableGroup.GetFilter(hierarchyColName)
       hierarchyFilterHandle.Visible = True
       dynamicSubGroup.Add(hierarchyFilterHandle.FilterReference)
```